# Как из проекта сделать библиотеку?

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Хочу из проекта сделать библиотеку, что бы использовать ее. Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Как создать библиотеку при создание проекта](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/images/xlibrary10.png.pagespeed.ic.vFbAQZH1cH.png)

[Как сделать проект библиотекой](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/images/xlibrary20.png.pagespeed.ic.--LHsFy0L_.png)

[Как добавить библиотеку в проект](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/images/xlibrary30.png.pagespeed.ic.C6oekZBznQ.png)

[Источник](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html#androidjarfiles)

Comment: @psyhitus Это все? Как потом импортировать всю библиотеку в проект?

Comment: Это в eclipse. Лучше разберитесь как с помощью Ant собирать проект. Там все эти вопросы ещё проще.